Why do the Hooli engineers only figure out about middle-out compression so late in Silicon Valley?
In the season 1 finale, didn't Richard Hendricks literally explain onstage at TechCrunch Disrupt that he thought of middle-out compression after their... discussion...?
If so, why did it take the Hooli engineers so long to figure out that middle-out compression was viable, when they already knew that Pied Piper was using it?

It might help if you put here when the Hooli engineers figure it out - I've watched the show but its not recent so have forgotten if this is a couple of episodes or seasons.

Knowing something can be done is not the same as being able to do it.

They knew about the middle-out compression algorithm. Only in the second episode of season 3, 'Two in the Box', was the Nucleus team at Hooli able to figure out how it (potentially) works:

The Nucleus team crack the middle-out compression shortly before their contracts expire, and decide to take this knowledge with them.

The middle-out compression algorithm was invented for the show ("top-down" and "bottom-up" already existed through Shannon's and Huffman's algorithms), and Richard only introduces the concept to the audience at the TechCrunch Disrupt presentation we see in season 1 - he doesn't explain how it works.
